# nexus s rooting wifi error problem

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, samsung-nexus-s

So, I have unlocked my Samsung Nexus S that runs on Android 2.3.1 and i have rooted it. The problem now is that I cant open wifi anymore, it keeps telling me "error" whenever I click on wifi ..

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: All it says is "Error"?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the wifi tab it says error beneath it.... A friend told me to install a new "Kernel" but I dont want to overwhelm my android with custom made Kernels

Comment: Um, I don't think a kernel will "overwhelm" it.  You'd most likely need to replace the modem as well.  I recommend an entire custom ROM.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by restoring only the android "boot" module from the original rom backup:

I used the clockworkmod recovery which can also be installed from the rooted phone using the "rom manager" app. But instead of making a whole recovery, i simply went into advanced recovery options, selected the above mentioned backup folder, and selected to restore only the "boot" module:

- start clickworkmod recovery,
- select "backup and recovery"
- select "advanced recovery"
- select the image of the original backup (see below)
- select restore boot

This post describes how to restore your nexus s to original stock android and provides a backup of the original rom: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=884093

Comment: see also: http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/04/16/complete-guide-how-to-fully-back-up-and-restore-your-android-phone-using-nandroid-backup-and-clockworkmod-rom-manager/

Answer (score 0):

The same happens for me. When I use the 'fastboot boot *.img' command from my pc, the Nexus S boots into some (e.g. Netarchy) kernel, and everything except WiFi works.

I assume the problems lies with some kernel-modules (which can actually be on the device memory, outside of the kernel) which do not match the new kernel. Since some of the modules (e.g. for the gsm/gprs radio) are closed source, they are not updated to match newer kernels.

So you could try older kernel versions, or wait for updates from Samsung